# How to convert an image to grayscale in opencv

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert an image into grayscale.

1st approach

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread('dogs.jpg')
print(image.shape)
grayscale_image=np.zeros(image.shape[:2],np.uint8)




for i in range(image.shape[0]):
    for j in range(image.shape[1]):
        grayscale_image[i][j]=(image[i][j][0]+image[i][j][1]+image[i][j][2])//3




cv2.imshow("Grayscale Image - 1 ",grayscale_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

2nd Approach

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

image=cv2.imread('dogs.jpg')
print(image.shape)
grayscale_image=np.zeros(image.shape[:2],np.uint8)

grayscale_image=np.mean(image,axis=2).astype(np.uint8)

cv2.imshow("Grayscale Image - 1 ",grayscale_image)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

from my understanding both approaches does the same thing.
But I get different output for both,and the second approach produces the better output why??

Comment: also [ask] and [mre]

Comment: "different" needs elaboration. _show_ what you see.

Comment: if you are already using opencv just do:  `im_gray = cv2.cvtColor(image_bgr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`, no need to reinvent the fire, opencv has already functions to do the convertion.

Answer (score 1):

You likely encounter overflow in you first approach:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3).astype(np.uint8) + 100
>>> a
array([[100, 101, 102],
       [103, 104, 105],
       [106, 107, 108],
       [109, 110, 111]], dtype=uint8)
>>> a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2]
<stdin>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in scalar add
47
>>> (a[0][0]+a[0][1]+a[0][2])//3
15
```